# Laravel : Undefined variable reply

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I submit a Form from the create View, I get the error that a variable in my layout file has not been defined. Undefined variable: reply is shown, nothing has been posted.

my Route :

```
Route::post('/contact/search',array('uses'=>'HomeContactController@search','as'=>'home.contact.search'));
```

my Controller :

```
public function search()
{
    try
        {

            $q = Input::get('tracking_number');

            $reply = DB::table('contact')
            ->join('contact_reply', 'contact.id', '=', 'contact_reply.contact_id')
            ->where('tracking_number','like',$q)
            ->select('name','tracking_number','email','phone','subject','description','description_reply', 'created_at', 'created_date')
            ->orderby('created_date','desc')
            ->get();

            if (count($reply) === 0)
            {
                return  Redirect::route('home.contact')->with('danger','No reply .');
            }
            //$logs = DB::getQueryLog();
            //dd(end($logs));

            //var_dump($contact);   
            return View::make('home.pages.contact', compact('reply'));

        }
        catch ( ModelNotFoundException $e )
        {
            return Redirect::route('home.contact')->with('danger','Request is not valid.');
        }
}
```

my View :

```
<section>
        <table class="standard-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mail</th>
                    <th>Tell</th>
                    <th>Text Reply</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach ($reply as $rep)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $rep->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rep->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rep->phone }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $rep->description_reply }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </section>
```

Comment: What happens when you dd($reply); before returning the view?

Comment: Perhaps your query is returning 0 results and redirecting back to `home.contact`? `reply` would not be set then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not show any obvious issues and it is pretty straightforward to include variable in the view where not much can go wrong.

You can try forwarding the $reply via other methods, for example `return View::make('home.pages.contact')->withReply($reply);`

Check also `dd($reply)` in your controller before returning the view and and in view as `{{ dd($reply) }}`

Comment: Are you able to return any variable at all to any view?

Comment: in view i use any variable, but this methods "search", reply variable in my layout file has not been defined.

Comment: If you happen to use Redirect, then you need to use Session::get("reply") to get the variable value.